# The given path's format is not supported. Just started using C#

Tags: c#, xml, textbox

Ok, so I just started teaching myself C# today, and I have finally gotten completely stuck. I am trying the use a browse option to select a file. The file path will then be displayed in textBox1. Then I need what is textBox1 to be loaded by clicking the Launch button.

I currently have textBox1.Text set as the location of the file. When I type \TestList.xml into the textbox, it goes through fine and does what it is supposed to. Any other time however, like if I typed c:\TestList.xml or c:\TestList.xml it just says that it cant use the textBox1.Text format as a file location. Any idea how to fix this? here is the code. I added a bunch of dashes next to the line that is causing the problem. Thank you very much for any help with this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Combined
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            fdlg.Title = "C# Corner Open File Dialog";
            fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
            fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName;
            } 
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                          
                XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument();

            // causing problem
                xmldata.DataSet.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + textBox1.Text);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = xmldata.DataSet;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = "Unit";  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @asad: your ninja edit will make it hard for people to understand what the OP did wrong.

Comment: A good debugging strategy in situations like this is to inspect what is actually being passed to the method that is giving you the problem. In your case, set a breakpoint at the readXml() line and inspect the value of Application.StartupPath + textBox1.Text    
Alternately, change your code to:  
string whatIsWrong = Application.StartupPath + textBox1.Text;  
MessageBox.Show(whatIsWrong);  
xmldata.DataSet.ReadXml(whatIsWrong);  
You would see an invalid path like what @Ramesh showed.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you have typed in an absolute path, but it is then appended to another absolute path.

Comment: No one can see your problematic code now, but if you set a string variable to what you want to open (startup path + filename) you will realize your error if you print it to the console.  You would end up with a filename like c:\program filesc:\test.xml which is of course invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Application.StartupPath return the path of your running exe (Gets the path for the executable file that started the application, not including the executable name, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)), so if you give /TestList.xml it loads the file from the Bin

If you give the **c:\TestList.xml** , then it appends the path something like this

**"D:\urapppath\bin\c:\TestList.xml"**, its invalid right...